# Column size personnalization and \diaghead

Tags: tables, line-breaking

my aim to break table cell content lines automatically, and to reduce certain column size. The first column size cannot be reduce; I guess in cause is the `\diaghead` command.

Also,how can I get a better display of this table? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{table}[H]
    \topcaption{Comparaison des aspects généraux des méthodes d'analyse et de modélisation des connaissances.}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
    {
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}%
        {Auteurs}{Attributs}&\thead{Caractéristiques}&\thead{Objectif}&\thead{Destinaires}&\thead{Type}&\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\thead{Etendue}}&\thead{Propriétés}\\
        \hline
        \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{Ing pédagogique} & \footnotesize{Ing logicielle}& \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        \footnotesize{HNa XXXXXXXXXXXX} & \footnotesize{Basé sur l'analyse du comportement d’apprenants et l'analyse des traces d’usage (Usage Tracking Language)} & \footnotesize{Réingénierie d’un scénario pédagogique, Constitution d'une mémoire des indicateurs partagés} & \footnotesize{Enseignants} & \footnotesize{Patrons} & \footnotesize{x} & \footnotesize{-} & \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    %\end{center}
    \label{tab: aspectsGeneraux}
\end{table}
```

The rendering of that code can seen here: [image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://tonguim.free.fr/texchange/breakLines.png))</sub>

Comment: please always make your example a complete document so that people can use it to test their answers, your fragment uses many unspecified packages `H`, `\topcaption`,`\thead` are presumably defined somewhere...  it isn't clear what you wnat to change, currently you have specified the width of each column, you could clearly change those widths making some wider and some narrower, but you need to say which. The final vertical rule is missing as you don't have enough `&` in some rows.

Comment: I have edited my example by adding the document header.

Comment: I tried to made the first column from left narrower, but couldn't change its width, I cause because of the \diaghead command.

Also, there is the header of the second column from left that still refuse to automatically breaks.
I wish the lines would break automatically.

Comment: tex doesn't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, if you need that add `\hspace{0pt}` at the start of the cell

Comment: the example still can't be processed as posted, please add \begin{document} \end{document} and any other needed lines, conversely enumerate, verbatim packages (at least) are _not_ needed for this example. It really helps if you make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

something like this but it is still squeezed, perhaps set it landscape? I removed the diaghead as I couldn't get it to fit in any reasonable way, perhaps the table caption could be adjusted so that the column/row label isn't needed.

The usual advice here is to use `booktabs` and avoid vertical rules, but hard to suggest that layout if you really have so many empty cells.

[image]

Note this is a *complete* document so you can run the example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage{topcapt}


\begin{document}




\begin{table}
\centering\footnotesize
    \topcaption{Comparaison des aspects généraux des méthodes d'analyse et de modélisation des connaissances.}

        \begin{tabular}{
|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.10\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.15\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.15\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.08\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.08\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.05\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.05\textwidth}|
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}\nobreak\ignorespaces}p{0.05\textwidth}|}
        \hline
&
Cara\-ctér\-ist\-iques&
Objectif&
Dest\-in\-aires&
Type&
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Etendue}&
Prop\-riét\-és\\
        \hline
         &  &  & Ing pédagogique & Ing logicielle& &&\\
        \hline
        \hline
        HNa XXX\-XXX\-XXX\-XXX & Basé sur l'analyse du comportement d’apprenants et l'analyse des traces d’usage (Usage Tracking Language) & 
Réin\-gén\-ierie d’un scénario pédagogique, Constitution d'une mémoire des indicateurs partagés & Ensei\-gnants & 
Pat\-rons & x & --- & \\
        \hline
         &  &  &  &  &  & &\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \label{tab: aspectsGeneraux}
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```